# IndexOutOfBoundsException when restoring navigation tab state

Tags: android

I'm using action bar tab navigation and when I rotate screen I get IndexOutOfBoundsException

According to logcat problem is in `getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));`

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current tab position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current tab position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getSupportActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
```

**EDIT**
I found the problem. I use AsyncTask to gather all info that will be showed in tabs and I add tabs in `onPostExecute`.

`onRestoreInstanceState` is called before `onPostExecute` so the tab count is still 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `onSaveInstanceState` is called when the screen is rotated.
Due to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) "*the method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the activity in such a background state*".

Did you check, whether the function is called when the screen is rotated?

Comment: It is called, if I put System.out.println() inside that method it prints message to logcat.

Comment: Hm.. what does he tell you, if you call `getTabCount()` when storing and when restoring? Also - to ensure - do you get the same int-value on restoring as you save on storing?

Comment: If I call `System.out.println(getSupportActionBar().getNavigationItemCount());` in `onRestoreIn......` i get 0 always. in `onSaveInstanceState` i get correct tab count.

Comment: I found the problem, stupid of me really, edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`if (savedInstanceState!= null && savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM) >= 0)`

instead `if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM))`